# How to get the details of the all Azure VM's with respective all Tag associated with it in excel sheet with the help of powershell?

Tags: excel, azure, powershell

How can I write a PowerShell script to get the report of all azure VMs in an excel spreadsheet, which includes the All tags associated with that, RG, and subscription?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the Powershell Script by following steps:

1. Install `az` modules in your local machine (Install-Module -Name 'Az' -allowclobber -scope currentuser)
2. Connect to your Azure subscription using this cmd (connect-Azaccount).
3. Use `Get-AzVm` [Get-AzVM (Az.Compute) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-8.1.0) to get the list of VM under the subscription and assign the output to a variable and by using the for each loop [about Foreach - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2) iterate the list in the variable and project the output to csv file using the [export-csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2).